# global event loop(main thread) changed by threads in flask app

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio

I have four threads executing in order when flask app run.

and they implements its own event loop, and run_until_complete

```
    @staticmethod
    def _target_impl(
        loop: asyncio.BaseEventLoop,
        conn_task: Callable,
        fut: asyncio.Future
    ) -> None:
        try:
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            loop.run_until_complete(functools.partial(conn_task, fut)())
            if not fut.done():
                fut.set_result('complete')
        except Exception as err:
            fut.set_exception(err)
```

this target impls a event loop and connect to a websocket server.

args:

loop: main thread created

fut: a stop waiter create by loop upon

conn_task: coroutine implements a websocket connection client, stop by set 'fut' done

my question is:

1. When I start flask app and start these thread in order. **The first started thread will change MainThread's event loop and keep it running same as its own loop**, meanwhile these four thread running fine. So I can't run async function in my flask view.
2. Then I use ipython to import these thread instance and start in order. there is no running loop in my ipython's main thread.

Comment: Actually you need only one event loop in only one Thread - best speed. Anyway if you create loop in main thread and then give it as argument in `args` when you create new Thread - this is wrong.

Comment: I tried `asyncio.new_event_loop()` or `asyncio.get_event_loop()` in thread's `_target_impl` and still the same as above @ArtiomKozyrev

Comment: - one event loop in only one Thread - best speed.

I'm new to asyncio, how to create event loop for child threads @ArtiomKozyrev

Comment: no, you do not need multiple `asyncio` event loops in several threads, you need exactly one `asyncio`  event loop for the whole application

Comment: I didn’t make it clear in my main text. In fact, I want to use multiple threads to connect multiple websockets. @ArtiomKozyrev